# Does NSURLConnection on iOS support HSTS?

Tags: ios, hsts

I have an app for iOS that uses NSURLConnection to retrieve things from a server. Will enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on the server have any impact on the app? Will it refuse to connect to plain HTTP to that server?

Comment: Should be easy to test... If you do, you can answer your own question for rep

Comment: On iOS there is also app transport security which will prevent HTTP from being used in the entire app (kinda like a firewall blocking port 80). I believe it's enabled by default so you don't really need to care about HSTS as long as you have it enabled.

Comment: Thanks @AndréBorie. Even though it doesn't strictly answer my question, ATS is obviously the right way to get HSTS-like behavior in an iOS app.

Comment: I suggest using [TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit) : it's more secured because it implements [SSL pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).